# cant find css file in html (404)

Tags: html, css

Searched YouTube and can't find a solution for this problem.
when i run the code its says GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>itays website </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" , class="home">Home</button>
    <button type="button" , class="contact">Contact</button>
    <button type="button" , class="services">Services</button>
    <button type="button" , class="about">About</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: check if your .css file in same folder as you html file. add `./` before file name if in same folder.

Comment: @TheDuo yea i checked it

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the style.css file in the same directory as your html code.

**UPDATE**

I have the html code in the same folder as the style.css.
I made a simple style.css and it looks its run properly

[Here is a photo when i test it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzPjl.png)

One reason that you have this error is because you have something wrong in your .css file, like a picture in a wrong directory most probably

Here is an example :

```
body {
    background: url(./login_backround.jpg); // login_backround.jpg need to be in the same folder!
    background-size: cover
}
```

Comment: what do you mean how can i do that